# SqlConnection and SqlCommand with using statement

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I have a connection to a database set up like this to call a stored procedure.  I am just wondering if this is the best way to do this.
I have two using statements one for the sqlConnection and one for the sqlCommand (which I am not really sure if its needed)

```
using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(conString1))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd1.Connection = con1;

        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.CommandText = "updateVendorEstNo";
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plantNameNew", vPlantName.Value.ToString().Trim());

        var result = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
        result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        var resultDesc = cmd1.Parameters.Add("@resultDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
        resultDesc.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        con1.Open(); // open connection
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

        res = result.Value.ToString().Trim();
        resDesc = resultDesc.Value.ToString().Trim();
    }                
}
```

My biggest question is when I am doing :

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
```

Is it fine the way it is done right now.. or should it be more like,

```
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("updateVendorEstNo",con1))
```

Comment: Either way will work - which you'd know if you tested it. Just pick the one you like best. And yes, you should almost always wrap objects that implement IDisposable in a using statement.

Comment: There shouldn't be any impact on the `using` statement. It will continue to work in both cases. The only difference is the constructor calls, There shouldn't be any impact.

Comment: I did test it. both ways worked.. but i wasn't if one was better performance wise .

Comment: The only real difference is readability. The `SqlCommand` is contained in the `using` block either way. If you were running multiple `SqlCommand`s, I would leave the command text out of the `using` block statement for clarity, but if only one command is being run, I tend to include it in the `using` line. I think it's largely a question of personal preference.

Comment: @psj01 Then benchmark it.

Comment: i wasn't asking the question for style tips.. i just wasn't sure if there is any advantage using one vs. the other..  sorry if the question wasn't clear enough...

Comment: @mason what does benchmarking it means?

Comment: It means run some tests to determine which is faster. There are various libraries that can make this easier and handle some of the nuances, such as [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). But, if you tested both ways and found out they worked, and you're not noticing any overt performance problems, then there's no need to worry about it. Worrying about performance before you have a problem is called pre-optimizing. And pre-optimizing is bad. Why waste time optimizing this code if it's not an issue? Surely other issues would be a better use of your time.

Comment: @mason sorry I am still kind of new at this. Learning as I go. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the way you have it is fine, because [the `using` statement will ensure that the object is disposed of either way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).